# Using accumulator to concatenate a list of numbers

Tags: syntax, conditional-statements, scheme, racket, function-call

I am trying to create a function to concatenate a list of integers into a single integer/string,
expected values:

```
(check-expect (concatNumbers (list 1 2 3 4)) 1234)
(check-expect (concatNumbers (list 0 4 3 2 1)) 04321)
```

my function:

```
(define (concatNumbers alon)
  (local
    ((define (inner list1 acc)
       (cond
         ((empty? list1) acc)
         (else
          ((string-append (number->string (first list1)) acc)
           (inner (rest list1) acc))))))
(inner alon "")))
```

but there is an error which I cannot understand:

```
function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received "3"
```

the tests im trying to find the values of:

```
(concatNumbers (list 1 5 7 8 9 3))
```

Comment: that's .... *not* a concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `cond` clause (I am guessing you are using the intermediate student language) consists of two things:

- a test expression which is either true or not, or `else` which is always true;
- an expression which will be evaluated if it's the first clause where the test expression is true.

So, look at your `else` clause:

```
(cond
  ...
  (else
   ((string-append (number->string (first list1)) acc)
    (inner (rest list1) acc))))
```

OK, well the expression is

```
((string-append (number->string (first list1)) acc)
 (inner (rest list1) acc))
```

So, if that's even legal in the language (it would be in full Racket), what it means is:

1. evaluate `(inner (rest list1) acc)`;
2. evaluate `(string-append (number->string (first list1)) acc)`, which had better result in a procedure;
3. call the procedure resulting from (2) on the value resulting from (1).

That doesn't look right, does it? For a start, what does `(string-append ... ...)` return?  My guess is 'not a procedure'.

Instead you probably want to call `inner` again with the appended string as its `acc` argument.

(And you will also have to do something else to get the right answer, but I will leave that, as it's interesting to learn.)